# HTML video player - cannot skip video and restarts if tab loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I want to create (or use a pre-existing) HTML video player that stops users from skipping the video and restarts the video if the tab loses focus. Are there any suggestions or tips for this? I truly don't know where to start and some brief Google research yields no helpful results. (A similar program is like EdPuzzle, only I want mine to restart the video upon losing focus.)

Comment: `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur` will tell you if the tab has/loses focus. to prevent skipping, hide the controls and just add your own overlay for play/pause and volume

Comment: @Offbeatmammal -- Thanks! Now, is there a way to restart the video if/when window.onfocus if false? And how do I hide those controls?

Comment: you hide the controls by not including the controls attribute. you restart the video by attaching an event handler to the onfocus event and setting the currentTime on the video to 0